# Ruby txt parser - Output following line on condition

Tags: ruby, parsing

I have a text file structured like this:

```
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
All Events Information: 1 : Timestamp: 08.11.2017 01:46:10
Message: DEBUG, Thread ID:12,63645705970991641611 - Request: POST https://some.url.com:8080/api/Customers/
{"json":"someValue"}
```

For every Message that contains the request URL `"/api/Customers"` I want to output the following line `{"json":"someValue"}`. If it doesn't, it should skip the whole block.

Here's what I have so far. It puts the line correctly, but I want to get the following line:

```
File.open("my_file.log", "r").each_line do |line|
    if line.include? "POST https://some.url.com:8080/api/Customers/\r"
        p line
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very simple solution:

```
def test
  show_next_line = false
  File.open("/home/gergra/code/test/my_file.log", "r").each_line do |line|
    if show_next_line
      show_next_line = false
      puts line
    end
    if line.include? "POST https://some.url.com:8080/api/Customers/"
      show_next_line = true
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not doing it as I'm still in the loop of this particular line, so it's just outputting the same. I somehow need to get to the next line

Comment: If you delete the "\r" in the include param is it working?

Comment: No, I'm still in the same line. I somehow need to get 'next' to work

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry. So, this is the correct version